# How can I convert netstat output to a variable

Tags: bash, scripts

```
netstat -an | grep :443 | grep -v TIME_WAIT | wc -l
```

How do I convert this retunring value of 171 to a variable `foo` so that If I enter `$foo` it will return 171.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, export the variable **foo** with your command:

```
export foo=$(netstat -an | grep :443 | grep -v TIME_WAIT | wc -l)
```

Then, `echo $foo` should return what you want.